# Animações são mesma coisa que transições?

Tags: html, css

Eu estou estudando *CSS* porêm com algumas dificuldades para compreender algumas coisas a questão é animações são iguais a transições ou semelhantes?

**Exemplo 1**

```html
<style>
    div {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background: red;
      transition: width 1s linear;
    }

    div:hover {
      width: 400px;
    }
</style>
<div></div>
```

No exemplo acima é igual ao de baixo

**Exemplo 2**

```html
<style>
    div {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background: red;
      transition: width 1s linear;
    }

    div:hover {
      animation: animar 1s linear;
    }
    
    @keyframes animar {
        50% {
          width: 400px
        }
    }
</style>
<div></div>
```

Qual são as diferenças entre os dois? se eu tiver um projeto e tiver apenas transições eu posso chamar de animações? ou vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma animação com `transition` **só acontece se houver uma interação do usuário**, pois ela tem apenas um estado inicial e um estado final, porém o estado final só aparece se o usuário fizer um `:hover` por exemplo.

Já o a animação com `keyframes` **não necessita da interação do usuário** para acontecer. Além disso, com ela vc pode controlar melhor como a animação acontece ao longo do tempo (*timeline*) e animar vários elementos ao mesmo tempo. Eu um formato mais robusto que o transition, porém nem sempre é o indicado.

As duas são animações, o ideal é que vc indique ao desenvolvedor ou ao time de trabalho que tipo de animação vc usou, se é com `keyframes` ou `transition` caso seja necessário.

Resumindo um `transition` nunca vai acontecer automaticamente, a não sei que o usuário interaja com a interface, já o `keyframes` pode ser, ou não, automático.

As duas tem performances semelhantes, o que vai mais afetar a animação são as propriedades CSS que vc vai animar como `margin` ou `width` e `height` exigem o *re-paint* da tela, prejudicando a `ux` dando a impressão que a animação está travando, já propriedades como `opacity` ou `transform` não afeta muito a `ux`, pois as animações ficam mais fluidas. Aqui vc pode ler mais sobre o assunto https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/

Olha nesse exemplo como o quadrado de baixo fica "tremendo" e o de cima não, pois o de baixo eu animei com `margin`, uma  propriedade não muito recomendado para animações...

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f0f 0%, #f00 100%);
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  animation: trans 2s infinite linear;
}
.box:nth-child(2) {
  animation: margem 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes trans {
  to {
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }
}
@keyframes margem {
  to {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: muito, obrigado!

Comment: @joãobatista legal que te ajudou, não deixe de estudar, Abs!